# assign millisecond precision to a datetime column returned in a SQLDataAdapter

Tags: sql, vb.net, t-sql, datetime, sql-server-2008-r2

**UPDATE**

I have tried this query from with in VS2008, trying a new query in Server Explorer.

```
SELECT        
   keyID, code, CAST(evnt_dt AS datetime2(7)) AS 'datetime2'
FROM            
   tblDT
WHERE        
   (keyID = 474)
```

and the new column still is returned as `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM`.

Original question:

I am trying to find a way to assign millisecond precision to a datetime column returned in a `SqlDataAdapter`, `dateValue.ToString("yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss.fff tt")`

The precision exists in the database table in SQL Server 2008 R2. When `SqlDataAdapter` populates the Gridview, the value is converted to `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM`, for display purposes. I would like it to display as noted above with ms precision.

```
da2.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1000 [keyID], [evnt_dt], [codes_ID] 
WHERE CAST(evnt_dt AS date) = @evntDate)
```

And bound to a Gridview after populating a datatable.

```
da2.Fill(ds2)
dt = ds2.Tables(0)

GridView1.DataSource = dt
GridView1.DataBind()
```

Is there any way to do this in the SQL statement, or other technique?

Thanks,

Comment: Why are you identifying a row based on the timestamp? What happens if two rows have the timestamp?

Comment: This is just a subset of the query, to establish the help request. Searching on a given date, but what to display the precision when it is passed to the gridview. @evntDate is actually from a calendar selection.

Comment: So I don't understand what's going wrong. What value are you passing to @evntDate? Have you debugged? What is the actual value that is being passed? We can't see that, so it's very tough to offer guidance. I still suggest that it's a terrible idea to identify rows by their timestamp...

Comment: Agreed but that is the requirement I am facing.

Comment: Without coming into who adequate is the query you are using, what you are asking is how you can input date records in a DataGridView with an accuracy upto the millisecond?

Comment: I need to display millisecond precision in gridview, given the SQLDataAdapter processing explained in the OP, hopefully without having to convert to databound fields or template fields.

Comment: The most direct way to accomplish that is by getting the right format directly from the query (I guess that you cannot convert the given column in the DB into text and set the format you want there); it does not sound too easy but I guess that it is doable. Unfortunately I am not a SQL expert and don't know how to do that. The other option would be modifying the contents in dt (or in the DGV directly), but I understand that this is your plan B.

Comment: @varocarbas, correct my post is lookikng to get the format directly from the query. I am trying to avoid custom coding the Gridview or looping the datatable.

Comment: Are you looking for CONVERT rather than CAST, plus a style that includes milliseconds such as 109?

Comment: I suppose that may do the trick, but I have tried to perform this at the SELECT stmt.

Comment: With your SQL as shown, you are returning a datetime. The formatting is taking place in the binding to the gridview; don't forget, if you run the query in SSMS or SE, you are once again seeing it formatted into a string. You are not seeing the 'real data' in either case.
YOu could fix this in the format setting within the binding, or you counld CONVERT the  datetime value to a string with a format such as 109.

Comment: How could I go about fixing this in the binding? Are you saying I must iterate through the datatable?

Comment: @peterg, Please submit your comment as an answer so I can accept it as such. I have solved based on your input.

Comment: @htmllh there you go - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your SQL as shown, you are returning a datetime. The formatting is taking place in the binding to the gridview; don't forget, if you run the query in SSMS or SE, you are once again seeing it formatted into a string. You are not seeing the 'real data' in either case - it's easy to think that you are seeing the data 'how it really is' but of course it is always being formatted somehow in order to get it onto the screen.
You could get the result you want via the format setting within the binding, or in the query you could CONVERT the datetime value to a string with a format such as 109.